# How to pass array of objects to jade display in view?

Tags: json, node.js, express, twitter, pug

I am using a twitter node module to retrieve searches using the api and putting them into an array of objects stored in a variable called "tweets" that looks like this:

```
[ { created_at: 'Sun Jul 24 20:32:34 +0000 2016',
   text: '2 Timothy 1:7 #nofear #power #love #sound-mind',
   user: 
     { id: 90281227, 
       name: 'Anavella', 
       screen_name: 'anavellar' } }, 
 { created_at: 'Sun Jul 24 20:32:34 +0000 2016', 
   text: 'Look, then, that the light in you is not darkness.Lucas 11:35 #Love,
   user: 
     { id: 197893427,
       name: 'Sandra Melanny Rojas',
       screen_name: 'MelannySan' } } ]
```

when I print it out on the console. I am rendering the view using the following line of code:

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Express', data: JSON.stringify(tweets) });
```

On the jade template I have something like this:

```
block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
  -var jsonObj = !{JSON.parse(data)}
  if jsonObj
    ul
      each tweet, i in jsonObj
        li= tweet
```

but I get a unexpected token error.

Essentially, what I am trying to do is pass the array of objects that I created in index.js to the index.jade view and be able to iterate through the array of objects so that I can display the result in the view.

**UPDATE**

I removed the !{} from JSON.parse(data) making it

```
-var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data)
```

which ended up eliminating the unexpected token error. In this case, I still get an error that says "Unexpected end of JSON input" referring to the line I just edited.

Comment: 1) Are you sure that array needs to be parsed as JSON? 2) Have you tried parsing the data in the controller?

Comment: I stringified it before passing it into the jade view which is why I am parsing it. I have tried parsing it in the controller and it logs out the sample array I put above. @pdoherty926

Comment: You should be able to just pass the array through to the view without string-ifying/parsing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not use stringify while passing your context data to your view:

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Express', data: tweets });
```

Now, in your jade, you can simply iterate through the array and print the object's properties using dot notation or square bracket notation like we normally do:

```
block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
  ul
    each tweet in data
        li= tweet.text
```